# Can early binding Types be refreshed in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: entity, dynamics-crm-2011, late-binding, early-binding

I've written a service that uses early binding types in dynamics CRM 2011. Now, I've updated one of my custom entity and created a few attributes to it of different types like `new_visitdate` and `new_visitonly`.

The problem is while updating the service and I am unable to find that my newly created attributes.

Can I refresh my early bind types so that I could retrieve latest attributes of an entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to regenerate your early bound types whenever you make a change to the data model.

Answer (score 0):

The Early Binding Doesn't have to be in Sync with the Actual CRM schema, as long as you don't attempt to set an attribute (or entity) in the EarlyBinding, that doesn't exist in the CRM instance.  And of course, you will need to regen the entities if you want to reference the new attributes you've added.

I recommend using the [Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/releases) to generate the entities.  It uses the same CrmSvcUtil that the SDK provides, but puts a UI around it so you don't have to mess with the command line: